# On the Mobius function over finite fields

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields

Let $\mu(n)$ be the Mobius function, which is equal to $(-1)^r$ when $n$ is squarefree and composed of $r$ distinct prime factors and $0$ otherwise.
My question: is $\mu$ also defined over finite fields ? And if yes, what is the analogue of the RH ?

Comment: The classical $\;\mu\;$ isn't defined on *any* field, whether finite or infinite. It is defined on the natural numbers $\;\Bbb N\;$ , which aren't even a ring: t is an arithmetic function. Thus, if some function could be defined on finite fields that could ressemble the behaviour of the classical $\;\mu\;$, it would already be pretty different from it as to be called by the same name...

Comment: If $\Bbb{F}_q$ is the finite field of $q$ elements, then there exists a Möbius function on the polynomial ring $\Bbb{F}_q[x]$. A lot of number theory can be ported into such a polynomial ring actually. Yes, there is an analogue of the Riemann Hypothesis in that setting. It is actually a THEOREM, not just a hypothesis.

Comment: See [Michael Rosen's book](https://www.google.fi/imgres?imgurl=http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q%3Dtbn:ANd9GcRZmwqZO7waJ9R-TzDcMNScQMfaEfzutw7wGN43lZO2NMT4XWxq&imgrefurl=https://books.google.com/books/about/Number_Theory_in_Function_Fields.html?id%3DYWjmBwAAQBAJ%26source%3Dkp_cover&h=1080&w=719&tbnid=4dBjyuQCDONr-M:&tbnh=138&tbnw=92&usg=__xpx2KhH2IMwjlCg56P15b_yR6JQ%3D&vet=10ahUKEwiugejos5bYAhVIZFAKHW1ABXYQ_B0IjwEwCg..i&docid=VFT9ww7ENi-QfM&itg=1&client=firefox-b&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiugejos5bYAhVIZFAKHW1ABXYQ_B0IjwEwCg) for an IMHO excellent account of this analogue.

Comment: Basically, you need a domain to have a concept of a prime. And $\Bbb{F}_q[x]$ is a perfect analogue to $\Bbb{Z}$ in so many respects. UFD, Euclidean algorithm, finite quotient fields when you mod out maximal ideals,... Actually it is easier than $\Bbb{Z}$ given the status of RH.

Comment: The RH in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ is quite easy to prove because the zeta function is rational: $$\prod_{f \text{ monic irreducible } \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]} \frac{1}{1-t^{\deg(f)}} = \sum_{m \text{ monic } \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]} t^{\deg(m)} = \sum_{d= 0}^\infty p^d t^d = \frac{1}{1-t p}$$ From this, looking at $\log(\frac{1}{1-tp})$ you get $\# \{f \text{ monic irreducible}, \deg(f) =n \} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{d | n} \mu(d) p^{n/d}$

Comment: Yeah. I guess it's the variants of RH in extensions of the field of fractions that are more interesting - for the resulting $\zeta$- and $L$-functions actually have zeros on the criticial line. Those variants have been proven by Weil and others, lead to the Weil conjectures etc.